What can I do about a Schengen visa refusal from Greece that mentions a prior refusal from Sweden as the reason?
I’ve been traveling to Greece since 2016 as I took the Schengen visa for 7 times then I applied for one from 6 months and I got rejected from the Swedish embassy.
Now I applied for a new one from the Greek embassy and I was rejected again, when I asked about the reason this was their reply
“The refusal was issued in accordance with the Schengen code and it cannot be changed.
There is a serious rejection from an other country.”
What should I do?

What was the prior refusal reason given by the Swedish embassy?

Plan to travel to somewhere other than Greece? (or Schengen)

When did you apply to Sweden? What was your purpose of travel? It’s unclear in your question if you applied for a 6 month stay or a 6 month validity. Did you appeal the decision? For completeness, what is your citizenship and country of residence? In any event, it’s impossible to answer without knowing the prior refusal reason from Sweden.

The sentence you quoted doesn't mention Sweden or the earlier visa. A recent refusal would be visible to the Greek consular officer and there might be information that's prejudicial and damages your credibility but it still shouldn't lead to an automatic refusal, they are still supposed to pick a refusal reason.
There are however other possibilities:

A member state (could be any one of them, including but not limited to Sweden) asked to be consulted for all visa applications from nationals of your country (article 22 of the Schengen Visa code) and then gave a negative assessment on national security or public policy grounds
A member state (again, it could be any one of them, including Sweden) listed you (or an homonym) in a SIS alert, this would typically be mentioned explicitly in the refusal but there might be exceptions.

